# SharePoint 2013 - Display feeds from multiple sites

Tags: sharepoint-server, sitefeed

I would like to know if it's possible to display feeds from multiple sites in one single Site feeds webpart using OOTB features or programmatically ?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: SharePoint Server 2013 Enterprise edition